# How to use Django's template tag with Vuetify's input value?

Tags: django, vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to use Django's template tag with Vuetify's input value.
In Vuetify 's official document, it is written in the setting method of value as follows.
https://vuetifyjs.com/ja/components/text-fields#example-disabled-and-readonly

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6>
          <v-text-field
            value="John Doe"
            label="Regular"
            disabled
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

And I tried using django as follows

```
<v-form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <template>
      <v-form>
        <v-container>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6>
            {% for field in form %}
              <v-text-field
                value="{{ form }}"
                disabled
              ></v-text-field>
            {% endfor %}
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-form>
    </template>
</v-form>
```

And the result is like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyZtW.png)
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering the whole `form` in each iteration of your `for` loop, which is going to break your HTML. You probably want to do something like this instead to render the value of each field in the loop:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <v-text-field
        value="{{ field.value }}"    <!-- note: field.value, not form -->
        disabled
    ></v-text-field>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You are right! This is what I wanted to do.
Thank you so much!!